# Not able to retrieve session stored in switch/case in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, switch-statement, laravel-6.2

I am storing a session variable in a case (case a) using switch case and then trying to retrieve that session variable when I reach to another case (case b). But I always get as null.

I get the session variable when I am in same case. While saving a session variable in case a and retrieving it in case b I get null.

```
switch case:

  case a():
    Session::put('var', $text);
    break;

  case b():
    $var = Session::get('var');
    dd($var);
    break;
```

I am using Laravel 6.2.

Comment: Just an idea: Do actually use the same session when you try to get the value in _case b_? Meaning are you logged in with the same user?

Comment: I have an api /api/controller which doesnt require user to log in.
so when I pass a text to that api then the switch case part comes in.

could that be a problem?

Comment: Could you try `Session::save();` after `Session::put('var', $text);`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause.

Firstly, I had to add StartSession middleware in my route as I was using /api/

Secondly, I was using telegram bot api, so whenever a user sends a message using telegram it calls my api /api/message and for each request it was creating new session so I could not save anything in my session. Looks like I cant use session using telegram bot api.

Will save temporary user input in db, no choice.